# What happens if someone Doomblades a creature in response to you trying to give it Indestructible?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-indestructible

I got a bit confused about what would happen in this situation since the stack resolves in reverse order. So, the situation: I have a creature, and then I cast [Adamant Will](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAdamant%20Will%5d) on it causing it to be indestructible, my opponent then casts [Doom Blade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoom%20Blade%5d)- that would usually kill the creature. But the stack is in reverse so would doom blade kill the creature BEFORE it got indestructible?

Comment: The trick is that you do not “cast Adamant Will on it causing it to be indestructible.” It will only become indestructible when Adamant Will resolves, not when you cast it.

Comment: This is _exactly the point_ of the stack, and playing things "in response". The creature dies before the indestructible property reaches it.

Answer (score 8):

**Your creature will be destroyed**

As you correctly noted, the stack resolves in reverse order of casting, and if your opponent casts Doom Blade while Adamant Will is still on the stack, Doom Blade will indeed resolve first and destroy the creature. When Adamant Will would resolve, it will go to the graveyard without resolving  because it has no more legal targets.

Comment: I edited the last sentence fizzled because spells are no longer countered.

Comment: @Gendolkari, There's no reason to stop using the word "fizzle". It simply means "put in the graveyard as it would resolve" instead of "countered by the rules" now.

Comment: @ikegami You misread me. The post said countered; I changed it to not say countered, because the definition of “fizzle” has changed.

Comment: Ah. Didn't check original text (nor can I in this app). Comment made it sound like you removed "fizzled"

Comment: This also means that you could play them the other way round - cast Adamant Will in response to your creature been Doom Blade'ed, and it will survive as it became indestructible by the time Doom Blade resolves.